# Android Spinner like css tye

Tags: android, android-spinner

http://jinni.amtechgcc.in/upload/css type spinner.png

Hi

I am trying to integrate one spinner which is contain one sub item like i given url above.

Please give me solution it will be helpful me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to create spinner with only main list.

Display sublist in dialog when user touches item. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html - Adding List section

Or you can use ExpandableListView (ideally inside dialog) that contains list + sublists.